# How to use the Semaphore in Java

Tags: java, swing, loading, semaphore

I have a function that takes a while and want to display a waiting screen :

```
Loading.showSplash("Working...");           

for (FileListRow row : model.getList()) {
    performAction(row);
}

Loading.hideSplash();
```

The problem is that the performAction(row); seems to be executed before the loading screen and hence it defeat the purpose.

Any help on solving this to force the waiting screen to show before the rest is executed and to force the function to finish before the waiting screen goes away.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving this a shot. You should call all code that does GUI updates from the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Swing is not thread safe.

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                     Loading.showSplash("Working...");  
                }
            });

new Thread(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                    for (FileListRow row : model.getList()) 
                    {
                        performAction(row);
                    }
               }
            }).start();

Loading.hideSplash();
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Actually the loading screen does not even show now. Once the function I execute is completely done, then the loading screen shows up.

Comment: This doesn't wait for the action thread to finish before calling `hideSlash()`.

Comment: True. Then move Loading.hideSplash() into the thread after the for loop completes.

Answer (score 1):

Can I assume this is a Swing program?

If yes, then it looks like you're performing your long-running operations on the event dispatch thread. This is a bad idea; you should perform all long-running operations on a workert hread. See the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

And if you do perform long-running operations on a background thread, your definitely *do not* want to use a semaphore to suspend the GUI thread until those operations complete -- or even until they start. The GUI thread should be allowed to run freely and dispatch events, or your UI will have "lags," which are annoying to users. As other posters have indicated, your worker thread can use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` to update the UI.

Comment: Yes it is a swing program. Good comments thanks. 
I am going to go through the Tutorial and see how I can reorganize the code such that the long running function is on a worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are developing a Swing application.
Read the javadoc of the SwingWorker class : http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html.
The idea is to 
1. display your splash screen
2. start a thread which performs all your actions in the background. 
3. when the background operations are finished, hide the splash screen

The SwingWorker takes care of this. Note however that the background operations may not use any Swing-related component or class, since they're not thread-safe and must execute in the event dispatch thread (EDT).

Another, simpler approach would be to display your splash screen, and then use SwingUtilities.invokeLater to perform your operations and hide the splash screen. This way, everything will be done on the EDT, but the splash screen will be displayed before the other operations are performed. Note however that with this technique, the application GUI will be unresponsive until the splash screen is hidden.

Comment: Hum...interesting. It might be another approach in fact. The main goal of displaying the waiting screen is just for the users not to freak out and start clicking everywhere. If the application GUI is unresponsive until the splash screen is hidden, it is actually no necessary a bad thing. I have read the tutorial and your link and are familiar with the concept. Now it is about modifying the code to do just that.

Comment: +1 Here's a simple `SwingWorker` example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637725